# css hover size transition effect cross browser/fallback solution needed

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a fairly simple css3 markup that displays a little cool hover effect. I need a pre Internet Explorer 10 fallback. I also cant get it to look 100% right but never the less here is the code:

HTML

```
<ul class="ca-menu">
<li>
    <a href="#">
        <span class="ca-icon">$</span>
        <div class="ca-content">
            <h2 class="ca-main">Exceptional Service</h2>
            <h3 class="ca-sub">Personalized For You</h3>
        </div>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.ca-menu{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 20px auto;
    width: 500px;
}
.ca-menu li{
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    border-left: 10px solid #797979;
    transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}
.ca-menu li:last-child{
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.ca-menu li a{
    text-align: left;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: #797979;
    position:relative;
}
.ca-icon{
    font-family: Century Gothic, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #797979;
    line-height: 90px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 90px;
    left: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all 300ms linear;
}
.ca-content{
    position: absolute;
    left: 120px;
    width: 370px;
    height: 30px;
    top: 1px;
}
.ca-main{
    font-size: 30px;
    transition: all 300ms linear;
    font-family: Century Gothic, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    margin-bottom:-5px;
}
.ca-sub{
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #797979;
    transition: all 300ms linear; 
    font-family: Century Gothic, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    margin-top:-5px;
}
.ca-menu li:hover{
    border-color: #57C5E0;
    background: #797979;
}
.ca-menu li:hover .ca-icon{
    color: #57C5E0;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #57C5E0;
    font-size: 50px;
}
.ca-menu li:hover .ca-main{
    color: #57C5E0;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.ca-menu li:hover .ca-sub{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

Working Demo Click [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jtbhV/1/)!

The only thing in my markup that is css3 is the `transition` effect and I feel their should be an easy css2 substitute for older browsers. I thought Javascript but wasn't sure what. Any help guys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the jQuery UI [switchClass() method](http://api.jqueryui.com/switchClass/) to animate class changes. Change your `:hover` selectors to `.hover` and animate that transition:

```
$('.ca-menu a').hover(function() {
  $(this).parent('li').switchClass('', 'hover');
}, function() {
  $(this).parent('li').switchClass('hover', '');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LMZUv/